# Use R Selenium to deal with pop-ups

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, rselenium

How can I navigate to a link, click a link, and scrape data from there?

I tried this code, without success.

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX")
# click 'Quarterly' button...
```

Something that is kind of close, is this.

Testing updated code now; results below.

```
> rm(list=ls())
> 
> 
> library("RSelenium")
> startServer()
Error: startServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function in
    file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
    recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
    see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.
> mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
> mybrowser$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused
> mybrowser$navigate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX")
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
> mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//button[text() = '
+                       
+                       OK
+                       ']")$clickElement()
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
> mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//span[text() = 'Quarterly']")$clickElement()
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the case you run into this on the website.

[image]

You can just "click" the OK button via:

```
mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//button[text() = '

                            OK
                    ']")$clickElement()
```

And then you can click "quarterly" via:

```
mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//span[text() = 'Quarterly']")$clickElement()
```

(Hint: To identify these kind of errors it can be helpful to check the current state of the browser via: `remDr$screenshot(TRUE)`.)

I am not sure it is up to date, but certain data is also available via the API, you could check the quantmod package to get an easier access.

**Full example:**

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX")
mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//button[text() = '

                            OK
                    ']")$clickElement()
mybrowser$findElement("xpath", "//span[text() = 'Quarterly']")$clickElement()
```

Comment: I just updated my original question with the code you posted.  I'm getting this error: Error: attempt to apply non-function
Any thoughts?  Yeah, maybe the API would work.  I can certainly look into it.  I was curious to know about the web parsing option.  Maybe, though, that's too cumbersome.  If you have any additional ideas, I'd definitely be open to hearing about them.

Comment: just to be sure, my code uses your "mybrowser" element, which is part of your rselenium attempt, not the rvest attempt. Could you double check that?

Comment: I threw 'mybrowser' in there and I'm getting this error:
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: 1. Could you please ensure that you can navigate to the page you specified via `mybrowser$navigate("https://......")`  2. Could you specify which command throws the error you mentioned 3.Could you please run the "Full example" code in my edited answer. It might be the case that you modified the code and removed the spaces and line breaks from the `"//button[text() = '

                            OK` part. Thanks

Comment: I just added this:  Testing updated code now; results below.  My actual results are shown above, in my original post.

Comment: Ok, then your remote driver does not even `$open()`. Thats kind of a new question. Difficult to debug that over the internet. Funny to say, but did you try a restart? :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not going to work.  I'll go with the API solution.  Thanks for the help with this!!